# Unexpected "(" - Shell script works on CentOS with bash but not on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have the following script:

```
names=($(python3 script.py -p "$GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT" -c "$GIT_COMMIT" | tr -d '[],'))
```

It works on a Centos 6 machine with bash 4.1.2(2), but when trying to execute on Ubuntu I'm getting:

```
bashfile.sh: 1: bashfile.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: Please don't post incorrect information in your question. This is error message is not from bash. In this case, it was easy to guess what was wrong — but in many cases, if you guess wrong but present your guesses as certainties, you won't get useful answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This script works on bash 4.3.48. The problem is that you aren't executing it with bash. It's missing a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line at the top.

```
#!/bin/bash
names=($(python3 script.py -p "$GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT" -c "$GIT_COMMIT" | tr -d '[],'))
…
```

Without a shebang line, the script gets executed by the default sh implementation. On Ubuntu, that's not bash, but dash. Dash doesn't support arrays.